# About Swift closure captures a weak property

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, closures

Let us say we have a class A like below

```
    class SomeView {
       var didDoneSomething: () -> Void = {}
    }    
    class A {
       weak delegate: B?

       private lazy var someView: SomeView {
           let view = someView()
           view.didDoneSomething = { [delegate] in
              delegate?.someFunction()
           }
           return view
       }
    }
```

I was reading this article by Sundell
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/swifts-closure-capturing-mechanics/

It looks like you can directly capture any properties as long as those properties either contain reference types (class instances), or immutable value types.

I am not so sure if it has retain cycle problem or not. Should I use [weak delegate] or not?

Any suggestion? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `request` method is an instance function of ImageLoader, there should not be a retain cycle at all.

On the other hand, if we have something like this:

```
class ImageLoader {
    private let service: ServiceProtocol

    private let cache = Cache<URL, Image>()

    func loadImage(
        from url: URL,
        then handler: @escaping (Result<Image, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        service.request(url) { [cache] result in
            do {
                let image = try result.decodedAsImage()
                cache.insert(image, forKey: url)
                handler(.success(image))
            } catch {
                handler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This indeed creates a retain cycle because ImageLoader will have a strong reference to the service dependency, and `service` will reference ImageLoader (it calls self.cache) in its closure. In this case, `Cache` would need to be captured as a weak reference.